# How to use ajax in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax, json.net

How can I return a class object from Ajax in asp.net MVC....???

Example:

Ajax call from html:

```
$.ajax({ 
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Tutorial/Web/AlignmentRule/GetAlignmentDetails', 
            data: { alignmentRuleId: alignmentRuleId },
            success:
                function (data) {
                    alert(data.Id);
                        alert(data.alignmentData.Id);
                        $("#ruleName").val(data.alignmentData.Name);
                        $("#level").val(data.alignmentData.Id);
                },
            error:
                function () {
                    alert("Server Error!!!!");
                },
            dataType: 'JSON',
            async: false
        });
```

and Action method in contorller is:

```
public virtual JsonResult GetAlignmentDetails(int alignmentRuleId)
    {
        var alignmentData = _allignmentRuleRepository.GetAlignmentById(alignmentRuleId);
        return Json( alignmentData );
    }
```

And I want to return a list of alignmentRule class objects also....

Comment: What is the problem you have? If your want to return the alignmentData as a collection, you can iterate the collection in the success function using `$.each(data, function(index, item) { alert item.ID; ..`

Comment: but its not returning anything..its throwing an error even in this code...

Comment: Check your console for errors, but I suspect it should be `url: /AlignmentRule/GetAlignmentDetails,` or better `url: 'Url.Action("GetAlignmentDetails", "AlignmentRule")';` assuming your controller is `AlignmentRuleController`

Comment: I used debuger on that and its working fine the action method of controller is being called properly but there is some problem in returning the data..

Comment: Try adding `dataType: json` in the AJAX method. Is the value of `alignmentData` in the controller valid?

Comment: ya i used debugger to check the values of alignmentData all are valid... putting dataType: json also didnt work.... it will be ok if I dont use json for transferring the data, all i want is to display the data returned by the ajax method on aspx...

Comment: You can also return a partial view instead of JSON and use `$('#SomeElement').html(data)`

Answer (score 0):

you can compose your return object as you want, for example, create a `ViewModel` as decorator to hold everything you want to pass, like:

```
var json = new JsonViewModel() {
               alignmentData = alignmentData,
               rules = yourRules
           };

return Json(json);
```

Comment: still same..it is showing the server error...if u cans send some code snipets of html page and controller...???

Comment: did you created your `JsonViewModel` object? are you passing the correct objects? if it's a server error, why don't you debug and add a breakpoint in the call so you can inspect what's going on? - You can't just copy paste the code I wrote, it's to give you an idea of how to pass multiple objects into your callback...

Answer (score 0):

The error is thrown because by default MVC framework does't allow you to respond to an HTTP GET request with a JSON (because of security reasons).
In order to make it work, when you retrurn Json in your action, you need to specify `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual JsonResult GetAlignmentDetails(int alignmentRuleId)
    {
        var alignmentData = _allignmentRuleRepository.GetAlignmentById(alignmentRuleId);
        return Json( alignmentData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**EDIT**

Annotate your action with [HttpPost] attribute.

For further investigation on this topic check this [article](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx/)

Comment: but I am using type : post that means the data will be transfered through post method only...